# How can I initialize 2D char array with space in c

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, input, char

I am doing a algorithm practice. Basically, the test case will input the shape of a number in several 3*5 matrix, and we need to get the number that the shape represents.

the input(test case) will look like this, which represents 0123456789):
[image: 0123456789]

So, I have created a 3*5 matrix，and I input some starts just for testing.
However, it did not work that well.

Since there is space in the input, so I assume that scanf will not work. I am using gets, for every row.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    int main(){
       char code[5][3];
       int i;
       for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
          gets(code[i]);
          printf("%d\n",i);
       }
    }
```

So, if I run this code, I could not get out of the loop because i value never go over 3. i value does increment until 3 and then back to 0.

[image]

Can someone tell me what is happening here?

new update:
[image]

Comment: You used too many newlines and printed the sublines in the wrong order.

Comment: First, do not _ever_ use `gets`. Use `fgets` instead. Second, the output in your question was not produced by your code. You code does not call any functions for printing strings. Please add the real code to your question.

Comment: Thank you point it out. I did not call any functions for printing strings. The ***  are the input, and the number(1,2,3) is the value of i I output.As Mr.Joël says, it might depends on the compiler and the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem with the code you gave, it must depends of the compiler and the OS it is running on.

BUT: there's at least something wrong this code : when `gets` reads 3 chars, it stores 4 chars in memory because of the ending `\0` added in the end. So you shouldn't read directly in the `code` array ; just read in another longer buffer and `memcpy` only 3 chars in the array.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char code[5][3];
    char line[100];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        fgets(line, sizeof line - 1, stdin);
        memcpy(code[i], line, 3);
        printf("%d\n",i);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, the size of character string I declared was [5][3]. So, if I reads 3 chars, it stores 4 chars in memory, I guess it is fine right? Since size of [3] means 0,1,2,3, which is size of 4.

Comment: No, that's no that. What I meant is : when `gets` read the three chars "***", it stores "***\0" in memory : it adds the zero ending string character. Since your array is only 3 chars sized, it'll make a memory overflow because of the fourth character.

Comment: So, I input shape of '0' ( as new update above ) , and then did "printf("%d\n",strcmp(code[1],code[2]));
    printf("%d\n",strcmp(code[2],code[3]));"

Comment: The result is -1 and -1 instead of 0 and 0. So, is it mean I cannot compare two lines like this;

Comment: You have to use the  `strncmp` or `memcmp` functions for comparisons : `strncmp(code[1], code[2], 3)` or `memcmp(code[1], code[2], 3)`

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But for strcmp, it will stop before the new line character. In this case,strcmp does not work. Does it mean that the new line character got is not at the end of string because of the using of memcpy? I could not find out the why the strcmp does not work.

Comment: `strcmp` stops at the end string `\0` character, not the newline `\n`. In your array, there's no newline and no string ending characters beczuse of `memcpy` as you guessed ; there's only spaces and '*'. And without `\0`, `strcmp` can't work.